# passing parameter from page to another and method in foreach param is empty

Tags: jsf, parameters

I have two pages I pass a parameter in the url which I retrieve in the second page where I have a foreach I display my offers but each offer contains a button I resubscribe when I click I must retrieve my parameter which I put in another method that identifies the user and add my offer to the cart.

when I do my debug at the moment when I click on I resubscribe it does not have the right method *handleAddProductBnf(paramBnf)*  which is triggered it is the 1st which displays the offers *getProductListBnf(param.bnfNum)* and the parameter passed in the method is empty.

the link param **bnfNum**

```
<a href="#{nfcore:link('/account/resubscribe.html')}?titleId=#{title.id}&amp;bnfNum=#{benef.numero}" class="btn">Resubscribe</a>
```

getProductListBnf(param.bnfNum)display my offers in the second page

```
<c:foreach items="#{renewController.getProductListBnf(param.bnfNum)}" var="prod">
        <ui:fragment rendered="#{prod.isNewOffer()}">
                        <ui:include src="../Offres/selectNewOfferBnf.xhtml">
                            <ui:param name="prodVO" value="#{prod}"/>
                            <ui:param name="paramBnf" value="#{param.bnfNum}"/>
                        </ui:include>
        </ui:fragment>
    </c:foreach>
```

method to add offre

```
<h:commandLink action="#{cartController.handleAddProductSingleTitleBnf(paramBnf)}" styleClass="btn-secondary">
                        Resubscribe 
                        <f:param name="productIdToAdd" value="#{curProd.id}"/>
                        <f:param name="ResubRank"      value="#{prod.rank}"/>
                        <f:ajax execute="@form" render=":nfform-displayCart-head :nfcartcount :nfglobalmessages" onevent="function(e){processCommandEvent(e, function(){showWaitDialog();}" />
                    </h:commandLink>
```

Comment: You should have used `<f:param>` there as well instead of `(paramBnf)` method argument.

Comment: @BalusC where? instead of "<a href ....bnfNum=#{benef.numero}""

Comment: In command action. See abovelinked duplicate. The EL expression in action attribute is only evaluated at the moment the form submit is processed. It is not evaluated during rendering HTML output containing the command link as you seemed to think.

Comment: @BalusC  The EL expression in action ?

Comment: the problem is when I click on I resubscribe I don't have the handleAddProductSingleTitleBnf(paramBnf) that triggers it's getProductListBnf(param.bnfNum)

Comment: Yup. And that's why you need to use `<f:param name="bnfNum" value="#{param.bnfNum}">` in command link so that it's available in next request as well.

Comment: @BalusC because each method is in a separate page. I need <f:param name="bnfNum" value="#{param.bnfNum}"> to pass the param